# How to run an function when anything changes in a dir with Python Watchdog?

Tags: python, filesystems, filesystemwatcher, watchdog, python-watchdog

I'm trying to use [watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog) to run a sync script whenever anything changes in a dir (except for one specific file). I simply copied the code from the readme (pasted below), which does what it says; log which file has changed.

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

I now want to run a function (which syncs the whole folder to a remote machine) whenever anything changes. So I just replaced `event_handler` with my own function. But that gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/watchdog/observers/api.py", line 199, in run
    self.dispatch_events(self.event_queue, self.timeout)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/watchdog/observers/api.py", line 368, in dispatch_events
    handler.dispatch(event)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'dispatch'
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

ps. I also want to exclude one file in the folder from being watched. Any ideas how I should do that?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to subclass and do whatever you want in dispatch:

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

class Event(LoggingEventHandler):
    def dispatch(self, event):
        print("Foobar")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    event_handler = Event()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

If you run the code you  will see `Foobar` outputted whenever a change is detected, to ignore files you may need to use [events.PatternMatchingEventHandler][1]. There are various methods in each

To do something when a something is  modified case we can override `on_modified`:

```
class Event(LoggingEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        print("Doh")
```

And running the code using the class above with `event_handler = Event()`  and changing a file will output something like:

```
Doh
Doh
Doh
Doh
Doh
Doh
Doh
2015-10-03 15:33:55 - Created file: ./test.txt___jb_bak___
2015-10-03 15:33:55 - Moved file: from ./test.txt to ./test.txt___jb_old___
2015-10-03 15:33:55 - Moved file: from ./test.txt___jb_bak___ to ./test.txt
2015-10-03 15:33:55 - Deleted file: ./test.txt___jb_old___
Doh
```

[1]: http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html#watchdog.events.PatternMatchingEventHandler `EventHandler` class you can override, it all depends on what it is you want to do. The `LoggingEventHandler` class itslef is a subclass of `watchdog.events.FileSystemEventHandler`:

**class watchdog.events.FileSystemEventHandler**
    Bases: object

```
Base file system event handler that you can override methods from.
```

**dispatch(event)**
    Dispatches events to the appropriate methods.

```
Parameters: event (FileSystemEvent) – The event object representing the file system event.
```

**on_any_event(event)**
    Catch-all event handler.

```
Parameters: event (FileSystemEvent) – The event object representing the file system event.
```

**on_created(event)**
    Called when a file or directory is created.

```
Parameters: event (DirCreatedEvent or FileCreatedEvent) – Event representing file/directory creation.
```

**on_deleted(event)**
    Called when a file or directory is deleted.

```
Parameters: event (DirDeletedEvent or FileDeletedEvent) – Event representing file/directory deletion.
```

**on_modified(event)**
    Called when a file or directory is modified.

```
Parameters: event (DirModifiedEvent or FileModifiedEvent) – Event representing file/directory modification.
```

**on_moved(event)**
    Called when a file or a directory is moved or renamed.

```
Parameters: event (DirMovedEvent or FileMovedEvent) – Event representing file/directory movement.
```

Comment: Why is `LoggingEventHandler` being passed in definition `class Event(LoggingEventHandler)`? I see it works either ways, please explain.

Comment: @CᴴᴀZ the `LoggingEventHandler` in `class Event(LoggingEventHandler)` is making it so that the `Event` class inherits from the `LoggingEventHandler` class. It works either way in this case probably because you are only using the `dispatch` method. However, if you wanted to use other parts of the `LoggingEventHandler` class they wouldn't work unless it is included

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways in python to follow changes made in a directory. One such way is to use the [`watchdog`](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/) module.

- Modules needed

  - To install watchdog run this command in the terminal.

```sh
pip install watchdog
```

If you want to make changes (currently in the root directory - `"."`) at the time a file/directory is created or modified, you can do so by using the following code:

```py
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler


class Watcher:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.observer = Observer()
        self.path = path

    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.path, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print("Error")

        self.observer.join()


class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        # if event.is_directory:
        #     return None
        print(
            "[{}] noticed: [{}] on: [{}] ".format(
                time.asctime(), event.event_type, event.src_path
            )
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    w = Watcher(".")
    w.run()
```

- `event.src_path` will be the full file path
- `event.event_type` will be *created*, *moved*, etc.

> If you want to ignore directory changes just remove the comment.

output:

```sh
[Tue Feb  9 00:16:02 2021] noticed: [created] on: [/Users/mt/Documents/stackoverflow/test.txt] 
[Tue Feb  9 00:16:02 2021] noticed: [modified] on: [/Users/mt/Documents/stackoverflow] 
[Tue Feb  9 00:16:19 2021] noticed: [created] on: [/Users/mt/Documents/stackoverflow/download.jpg] 
[Tue Feb  9 00:16:19 2021] noticed: [modified] on: [/Users/mt/Documents/stackoverflow] 
[Tue Feb  9 00:16:30 2021] noticed: [created] on: [/Users/mt/Documents/stackoverflow/new_folder] 
[Tue Feb  9 00:16:30 2021] noticed: [modified] on: [/Users/mt/Documents/stackoverflow] 
[Tue Feb  9 00:16:46 2021] noticed: [deleted] on: [/Users/mt/Documents/stackoverflow/new_folder] 
[Tue Feb  9 00:16:46 2021] noticed: [modified] on: [/Users/mt/Documents/stackoverflow] 
[Tue Feb  9 00:16:52 2021] noticed: [deleted] on: [/Users/mt/Documents/stackoverflow/download.jpg] 
[Tue Feb  9 00:16:52 2021] noticed: [modified] on: [/Users/mt/Documents/stackoverflow] 
[Tue Feb  9 00:17:00 2021] noticed: [deleted] on: [/Users/mt/Documents/stackoverflow/test.txt] 
[Tue Feb  9 00:17:00 2021] noticed: [modified] on: [/Users/mt/Documents/stackoverflow]
```

The `Observer` is the class that watches for any file system change and then dispatches the event to the event handler. It monitors the file system and look for any changes.

The `EventHandler` is an object that will be notified when something happens to the file system. In general a script is written to watch over any type of new files created or modified like csv, txt, xml, jpg etc.

For example, in the code below the `PatternMatchingEventHandler` inherits from the `FileSystemEventHandler` class and is used to do just that. Some useful methods of this class are:

- `on_any_event`: will be executed for any event.
- `on_created`: Executed when a file or a directory is created.
- `on_modified`: Executed when a file is modified or a directory renamed.
- `on_deleted`: Executed when a file or directory is deleted.
- `on_moved`: Executed when a file or directory is moved.

The below script is used to observe only *.csv* files using the `PatternMAtchingEventHandler`. You can further extend the patterns list if you want to observe more than one type of file.

```py
import watchdog.events
import watchdog.observers
import time
import sys


class Handler(watchdog.events.PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        # Set the patterns for PatternMatchingEventHandler
        watchdog.events.PatternMatchingEventHandler.__init__(
            self,
            patterns=["*.csv"],
            ignore_directories=True,
            case_sensitive=False,
        )

    def on_any_event(self, event):
        print(
            "[{}] noticed: [{}] on: [{}] ".format(
                time.asctime(), event.event_type, event.src_path
            )
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else "."
    event_handler = Handler()
    observer = watchdog.observers.Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path=path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

- Here with the help of `PatternMAtchingEventHandler` we can take advantage of processing just events related with files with the *.csv* extension.

output:

```sh
[Tue Feb  9 00:18:51 2021] noticed: [created] on: [/Users/mt/Documents/stackoverflow/test.csv] 
[Tue Feb  9 00:18:59 2021] noticed: [modified] on: [/Users/mt/Documents/stackoverflow/test.csv] 
[Tue Feb  9 00:19:12 2021] noticed: [deleted] on: [/Users/mt/Documents/stackoverflow/test.csv]
```