# Getting the filename using python Watchdog

Tags: python, variables, filesystems, output, watchdog

I am trying to get the name of a file that changes periodically. 
I am using watchdog to do this.

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

timestr = time.strftime("%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S")

class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        change_log = open('change_log_' + timestr + '.txt', 'aw')
        change_log.write('Time the file changed: ' + timestr + '\n')
        change_log.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_handler = MyHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path='.', recursive=False)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

For some reason this prints out about 62 lines in the "change_log" file. This is not very useful.
What I would like to do is to print the name of the file that changed, or store it in a variable to pass to my other module.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, if you need a file name, it is necessary to replace `'change_log_'` with `event.src_path`. See the [official code](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/_modules/watchdog/events.html#FileModifiedEvent) for more details.
You can also see the use of `event.src_path` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66110795/13155046) as I used it in the printout.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the event object that is sent to your handler includes the information that you seek:
http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html#watchdog.events.FileSystemEvent

Use the `src_path` property of the event object that's passed into your `FileSystemEvent` subclass handler method to get the filename.